# Lambda function in sorting/grouping

Tags: python, python-2.7, lambda

Im trying to understand how lambda works when used in groupby or sort functions, for example, i got an list of object, each object has two attributes: name and surname i want to group by name and surname and i tried two tings:

```
list.sort(key=lambda x: x.name and x.surname)
list.sort(key=lambda x: (x.name, x.surname))
```

Then the grouping

```
groupby(list, lambda x: x.name and x.surname)
groupby(list, lambda x: (x.name,x.surname))
```

What i noticed that  the first example of sorting and grouping doesnt work well, how does lambda works in this case?, is there any good way to test what the lambda function is doing?.

Thanks!

Comment: `x.name and x.surname` is a boolean expression, how do you expect that to reflect a partial order on which to sort?

Comment: Because `x and y` is _not_ the same as `(x, y)`, but rather `x if not x else y`.

Comment: @MichaelFoukarakis Yes, that seems obvious tbh.. i still dont understand why it does works when lambda is a tuple, i guess i will search a bit more of how groupby and sort deals with the parametter. Thank you!

Comment: The reason it seems to work when you return a tuple is that tuples are sorted on their elements in left-to-right order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's see what `lambda x: x.name and x.surname` returns for a given object:

```
class People(object):
    def __init__(self, name, surname):
        self.name = name
        self.surname = surname

name_and_surname = lambda p: p.name and p.surname
```

And then:

```
print(name_and_surname(People("Bill", "Gates"))) # will print "Gates"
print(name_and_surname(People("Name", "Surname"))) # will print "Surname"
```

It's because the evaluation of expression `x.name and x.surname` inside `lambda` is that it'll "split" expressions by `and`, then eval every single expression one by one, return the first `falsy` value or the last expression value no matter what it is, take `name_and_surname(People("Name", "Surname"))` as example

1. Eval `x.name` and get value `"Name"`, it's a `truthy` value, skip it
2. Eval `x.surname` and return it, which is `"Surname"`

So when you use `lambda x: x.name and x.surname` as your key function, actually you're using `lambda x: x.surname`

Comment: Perfect!, that answers how the lambda function is working, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The `key` argument expects a callable that receives an item in the iterable (list) as its first parameter. The callable is expected to return an object; and this object will be used to sort the output.

```
sorted([1,2,3,4,5])
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

sorted([1,2,3,4,5], key=lambda x: x * -1)
[5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

The same applies for `list.sort()`.